# How does gcc linker choose /usr/lib versus /usr/lib64 for library resolution?

Tags: gcc, 64-bit, porting, linker-errors, pam

My link line to gcc includes the following two entries in succession:

```
-lrt
-lpam
```

And this appears expanded as:

```
/usr/lib64/librt.so /usr/lib/libpam.so
```

Why is rt resolved to lib64 whereas pam is resolved to lib and consequently fails:

```
/usr/lib/libpam.so: could not read symbols: File in wrong format
```

Since it is only 32 bit ELF.  There is a /usr/lib64/libpam.so with is 64 bit ELF, why isn't it taken?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using -m32 to force 32-bits. Also inspect any environment vatiables that are being set by your .bashrc or .bash_profile that you are compiling under to determine if anything is cross-wired.

Comment: Norrid But I want to force 64 bit.  Tried -m64 and still /usr/lib/libpam.so is picked up.

Comment: What Operating System are you running? Have you re-installed the necessary libraries from their distribution package via apt-get or dpkg (on Debian or Ubuntu). Also - did you ensure that .bashrc and .bash_profile are clean?

Comment: This is Linux Centos 5.  All other aspects of machine and build are fine, it is just this one library which is coming from 32 bit version instead of 64 bit version even though both are available.